# Fundamental group of two circles joined

Tags: algebraic-topology

If we consider the union of two $S^1$ joined at point, the fundamental group is a non abelian free group with two generators. Intuitively is clear but, how can I prove it formally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is the free group on one generator ($\mathbb{Z}$)? If so, do you know the Seifert van-Kampen theorem?

Comment: You need Van Kampen theorem : Consider the open cover $\{U, V\}$ of $S^1 \vee S^1$ where $U$ contains the first circle plus a bit of the other circle, and $V$ the other circle plus the bit of the previous circle. $U \cap V$ is simply connected, thus $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V) \cong \Bbb Z * \Bbb Z$, since $U, V$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$.

Comment: I don't know that theorem... Is there an elemental proof without it?

Comment: @Cesare Not as far as I know, and probably there isn't one. You can prove that $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ is nonabelian by constructing an explicit covering space where lifts of the loops $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$($f$ is the loop around once circle, $g$ is the loop around the other circle) don't match, and that's about it.

Comment: @BalarkaSen did I miss something in my argument, or why didn't you carry yours through to compute the universal covering space directly?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Your argument is alright (+1). I'm just fussing at the word "guess", although don't take me seriously.

Comment: @BalarkaSen sure, thanks. It seems like just as natural a guess to me as that $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$, although naturally I didn't ever actually *make* the guess before I knew the answer!

Answer (score 4):

As you assumably had to learn covering space theory to compute $\pi_1(S^1)$, this may be the best approach. If you can guess that the fundamental group of the wedge is $G=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, then you can just observe that $G$ acts freely on the infinite tree with degree four at each node: the generator $a$ corresponds to moving right by one interval, and $b$ to moving up, if we visualize this graph embedded in the plane. The quotient by this action is $S^1\vee S^1$, and the graph is contractible, so it must be the universal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ with deck transformations isomorphic to $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you want a proof that doesn't rely on the Seifert van-Kampen theorem, here is one that uses maximal spanning trees instead.*

Let $\Gamma$ be the graph with a single vertex $b$ and two edges: $e_1$ and $e_2$.
That is, $\Gamma\cong S^1\vee S^1$.

Then a maximal spanning tree $T$ in $\Gamma$ consists just of the vertex $b$.
So the two edges are not in $T$, and hence $\pi_1(\Gamma,b)$ is a free group on two generators, where the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ generator is a loop going once around $e_i$.

*Note that the above proof relies on knowing that the fundamental group of a connected graph is a free group, and also uses some ideas usually found in the proof of the statement.
If you haven't come across that either then let me know and I'll try to add a further explanation.*

Pages 38 to 41 of [these online notes](http://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2014/3073/12/tg230911.pdf) might prove useful for you.